# How send a value with a href id to a modal

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog, href

Im trying to make a item editor.

For example:
I have a product and I want to remove the Serial number of it.(It's all stored in a database)

So I press the minus icon I 'borrowed' thats located next to the product's name:

```
<a href="#RemoveSerialNumberModal" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-minus"></i></a>
```

This opens a modal named 'RemoveSerialNumberModal' with a 'Are you sure' button.

This works all fine, but there are multiple products underneath each other and how can I tell the modal on what product it needs to remove the serial number? (All product have there own pair of icons).

The modal it's code is in the same file as the product list. But not in the same foreach loop.

I prefer to not use JS, but if there is no other way. It has to do.

**---------------EDIT---------------**

The products do have there own `id` ofcourse.

**---------------EDIT---------------**

Here is the modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div id="RemoveSerialNumberModal" class="modal hide fade">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="close">&times;</a>
            <h3>Update serienummers</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Selecteer het serienummer dat je wilt verwijderen.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Sluiten</button>
            <button id="RemoveSerialNumber" class="btn btn-danger eerste" type="submit">Verwijderen</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: use `data-id` attribute

Comment: beside the `data-toggle` I guess? And how do I fetch this attribute in the modal?

Comment: how you triggered the modal ?

Comment: I guess with the `data-toggle="modal"` in by the icon?

Comment: try to modify it..if you are not sure what actually happens

Comment: If I remove the `data-toggle` it doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96012/discussion-between-yesbe97-and-raveenanigam).

Answer (score 0):

Use data attribute and class names to toogle while clicking:

```
<a class="click" href="#RemoveSerialNumberModal" data="2121" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-minus"></i></a>

$('.click').click(function(){
   $('.click').removeClass('clicked');
   $(this).addClass('clicked');
});

$('#RemoveSerialNumberModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) { // triggered when showing the modal
    var data = $('.clicked').attr('data');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I fetch this attribute in the modal?

Answer (score 0):

Use `data-id` attribute.

I guess in your modal you have the below html :

```
<input type="text" name="yourid" id="yourid" value=""/>

//triggered when modal is about to be shown
$('#RemoveSerialNumberModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

    //get data-id attribute of the clicked element
    var yourid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');

    //populate the textbox
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="yourid"]').val(yourid);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I fetch this attribute in the modal?

Comment: Well that's the problem. I'm editing someone's code and he isn't using that kind of code to trigger the modal

Comment: See the edit in my question. There is no JS with the id RemoveSerialNumberModal. So I can't show it to you.